# Регулярное выражение для валидации пароля

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярку:

1. Минимум 1 латинский символ нижнего регистра
2. Минимум 1 латинский символ верхнего регистра
3. Минимум 1 цифра
4. Общая длина 6 и более символов
5. Запрещаются любые другие символы по типу "_-**/+)*&%@#" и тд.

Я написал такую:

```
^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,})$
```

Но она захватывает и запрещенные символы. Как исключить их из шаблона?

Comment: [`^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^\d]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/bBsrHC/1)

Comment: @tocic спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
^(?=.{6})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{6})` - в строке должно быть минимум шесть символов
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - в строке должна быть минимум одна буква из набора `a-z`
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - в строке должна быть минимум одна буква из набора `A-Z`
- `(?=\D*\d)` - в строке должна быть минимум одна цифра
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+`  - одна и более цифр или букв
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: А не могли бы вы мне поподробней объяснить конструкцию (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) ? Для чего мы пишем перед * [^a-z]? За что вообще отвечает левая сторона выражения? Знак "^" насколько я знаю это отрицание, то есть символы внутри этого класса не должны присутствовать

Comment: @Effex `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - это позитивный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия сразу после текщей позиции ноля и более символов, отличных от `a-z`, сразу после которых есть буква из набора `a-z`. Это принцип контраста, помогающий создвавать более эффективные шаблоны, напр. по сравнению с `(?=.*[a-z])`.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде в целом вник